# React redux cleaning “one-timer” API calls data from store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

My app has currently implemented api middleware which is handling all the API calls of the app.

Response data and status of every of these api calls are saved to the redux store. Many of these actions (e.g. Login, logout and others) could be called as “one-timers”, because after they are dispatched, only one component is affected (and only once) and theirs response data and status are no longer needed for the app (for login I’m saving access tokens with other reducer which is called by own action from api middleware) which means that store is being bloated by no longer needed data.

Is there any way or “best practice” to somehow clear this response data after components recieve props about response from redux store (without sending for example clear() action after every single time component recieve props - repetitive code)?

**UPDATE 1:**

Is it even "best practice" to have all the api calls handled by redux? I was thinking about separation of redux api calls and basic component api calls but I cant stop to think, that it is not good practice to have it separately. I would like to have it unified.

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/tree/master/app) how was made connection of reducers to component with `inject` - it uploads component with its reducer\saga\graphql\etc... and probably can be removed on unload of the component;

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I created abstracted API reducer that is handling all the api calls and then updating "entities" object in store, where It is saving data from API calls by theirs label.. for example `state = {auth: {...}, ..., entities: {LOGIN: {data: ...}, LOGOUT: {data: ...}, USERS: {data: ...}}}` ... Couldn't I just somehow (maybe by another middleware) handle this for example like,, when data are saved and used once, purge it from store?